# Why my custom search filter in vue.js can't work?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli

I can't understand where is my fault . I try to make a custom search filter.I make a search box Where I search anythings but when it is matching in my list it gives me matching output only .But its not working .It's not look like dynamic.I am using vue 2.Hopefully I forget to add something in my computed property

```
  <template>
      <div class ="container">
        <div class="new">
          <form >
          <h1><label>Enter country name:</label></h1>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" v-model="search">
          </form>
    
        </div>
        <div class='new'>
          <ul>
            <li v-for="country in countries">{{country.name}} 
    
              <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere dignissimos architecto quia, quisquam ad similique corporis. Laborum, error id qui consequuntur facilis est delectus velit vel ea nisi repudiandae doloribus. </p>
              
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        
      </div >
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      data(){
        return { 
          countries:[
           
           {name:'AMERICA'},
           {name:'INDIA'},
           {name:'PAKISTAN'},
           {name:'SRILANKA'},
    
          ],
          search:'',
        
         }
      },
      computed: { 
        newfuntion(){
          return this.countries.filter((funtion)=>{
            return funtion.match(this.search)
          });
        }
       }
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: what you explain what you mean when you say "it's not working"? what output does it give you? can you try outputting to see where things are going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are not using your computed property in your v-for.

Try changing it to this: `v-for="country in newfuntion"`